# R Hourly Heatmap with adjusted Dates

Tags: r, ggplot2, heatmap, lubridate

I'm new to r and tried the hourly heatmapt from the r grah gallery:

https://r-graph-gallery.com/283-the-hourly-heatmap.html

My question is, if it possible to adjust it that way, that the x axis ish shown with the correct amount of days in the month(example: Jan 1 … 31, Feb 1 … 28)

I tried to change scale_x_continuos with scale_x_date but it didnt worked as expected.

Comment: I assume that the x axis would need to be "free" using something like ```facet_grid(year~month, scales="free_x")```

Answer (score 2):

You can amend the code as folows, using a custom labelling function in `scale_x_continuous`:

```r
ggplot(df, aes(day, hour, fill = temp)) +
  geom_tile(color = "white",size = 0.1) + 
  scale_fill_viridis(name = "Hrly Temps C", option = "C") +
  facet_grid(year~month, scales = 'free_x') +
  scale_y_continuous(trans = "reverse", breaks = unique(df$hour)) +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = ~c(1, 10, 20, floor(max(.x, na.rm = TRUE)) -2)) +
  theme_minimal(base_size = 8) +
  labs(title= paste("Hourly Temps - Station", statno), x = "Day", 
       y = "Hour Commencing") +
  theme(legend.position = "bottom",
        plot.title = element_text(size = 14, hjust = 0),
        axis.text.y = element_text(size = 6),
        strip.background = element_rect(colour = "white"),
        axis.ticks = element_blank(),
        axis.text = element_text(size = 7),
        legend.title = element_text(size = 8),
        legend.text = element_text(size = 6)) +
  removeGrid()
```

[image]